# How is INativeElementView supposed to be implemented?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, uitableview

I was trying to implement `ListViewCachingStrategy=RecycleElement` in a Xamarin.Forms xaml page and everything displays correctly until I try to scroll. Then I get an exception that says that INativeElementView needs to be implemented. I designed the views in each native platform's ui designer and have a custom renderer for each. This crash does not happen if I use `RetainElement` instead of `RecycleElement`. Any ideas or suggestions?

Edit: My view that I created in the designer is called `FeeViewCell` and if I understand it right that is where INativeElementView is supposed to be implemented (in FeeViewCell.cs). My problem is now that casting to an element returns a System.InvalidCastException saying that the specified cast is not valid. Here is my code implementing `INativeElementView`:

`public Element Element
{ 
    get
    {
        return this.ToView() as Element;
    }
}`

I also have this as a question on the Xamarin forum [here.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/215677)

Comment: FWIW, to clarify this Q&A for others, I think your cross-platform X-Forms class `FeeCell` is `public class FeeCell : ViewCell`.  Then `FeeViewCell` is the platform-specific class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INativeNativeView` interface needs to be implemented on the custom cell class. In my example in iOS I in the custom renderer provides an item that comes from the pcl in my case a `FeeCell`. 
This is part of my custom renderer

```
public class FeeCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
        {
            var x = (FeeCell)item;
            //Do whatever you need to here.
         }
      }
```

This is part of my custom ui class:

```
public partial class FeeViewCell : UITableViewCell, INativeElementView
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString(nameof(FeeViewCell));
    Element _element;
public Element Element
        {
            get { return _element; }
            set { _element = value; }
        }
}
```

It also works to do this:

```
public Element Element
        {
            get { return new FeeCell(); }
        }
```

Comment: While either of those implementations will avoid the immediate symptom of the missing INativeElementView, AFAIK, **neither implementation** will successfully **recycle** elements. The first implementation will always return `null`, because the setter is never called. I think that will crash later (if use in a long list that goes offscreen, and a cell is recycled while scroll the list). The second implementation might be better - it does return an element, but it creates a new element each time it is called. See Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Cells/ViewCellRenderer.cs for example.